# IC chip for PCB to stabilize 12v input?

Tags: power, pcb, surface-mount

Hi I'm wondering if there's any SMD IC chip to stabilize a 12v input to a stabilized output? I need something like that to regulate power on PCB. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to create a stabilized 12V output from a 12V input it will be a bit complex (or a bit expensive) because the regulator will need some voltage to work with so the 12V will have to be boosted, then regulated. Some switching topologies such as SEPIC can do this with a single chip, but the details will depend on current draw and other requirements. This point was made when you asked a similar question here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/154099/having-the-same-source-for-power-supply-and-positive-input-for-a-single-supply-b

Answer (score 1):

The device you want is called a "voltage regulator" - there are a great many voltage regulator integrated circuits commercially available.

To choose a suitable regulator, you will need to know the desired input voltage range, output voltage, desired output current, and desired package.

You can search for appropriate parts at such places as Digikey and Mouser, and other electronic distributors.